# file_get_contents from yii2 project always return login page

Tags: php, yii2

i have 2 projects (A using Yii2 and B using plain PHP).

I want B to get content of file from A using `file_get_contents`.

But every time B request to A, it always gives me A login's page.

Heres my code...

**AuthController.php**

```
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['service'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['service'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],

        ];
    }

    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        if ($action->id == 'service')
            Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }


    public function actionService()
    {
        $status = 200;
        $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' .       $this->_getStatusCodeMessage($status);
          $content_type="application/json; charset=utf-8";

          header($status_header);
          header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
          header('X-Powered-By: ' . "Nintriva <nintriva.com>");
          echo json_encode(["hello","w"]);       
    }

    private function _getStatusCodeMessage($status)
  {
      $codes = Array(
      200 => 'OK',
      400 => 'Bad Request',
      401 => 'Unauthorized',
      402 => 'Payment Required',
      403 => 'Forbidden',
      404 => 'Not Found',
      500 => 'Internal Server Error',
      501 => 'Not Implemented',
      );
      return (isset($codes[$status])) ? $codes[$status] : '';
  }

}
```

**b.php**

```
$url = 'http://localhost/now/basic/web/index.php?r=auth/service';
$result = file_get_contents($url);
print_r($result);
```

Is anything wrong?
Thankyou

Comment: You have to disable `AccessControl` filter for your action...

Comment: Like Double H said, you are trying to access a page that requires a login without logging in. So of course you get the login page all day every day no problem. To get around that you should either disable the AccessControl if it is appropriate or implement some other sort of authentication between the 2 servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the rules. make it like this

```
'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['service'],
                        'allow' => true,
                    ],
                ],
```

just remove

```
'roles' => ['@'],
```

or just add this

```
'roles' => ['?','@'],
```

Comment: it gives me this error
Call to a member function checkAccess() on null

Comment: try this. it will allow you even not login